# how to create new json from existing json

Tags: angularjs, json

//Existing Json that i have

```
    [
    {
          "Id":1,
          "Authors":[
             {
                "Id":10,
                "Name":"Arun"
             },
             {
                "Id":14,
                "Name":"Arjun"
             }
          ],
          "tags":[
             {
                "Name":"Java"
             }
          ]
    },
    {
          "Id":5,
          "Authors":[
             {
                "Id":7,
                "Name":"Shyama"
             }
          ],
          "tags":[
             {
                "Name":"C#"
             },
             {
                "Name":"C++"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

//New Json (converted)
//Here i want to combine both the author

```
    [
    {
          "Id":1,
          "Authors":"Arun, Arjun",
          "tags":"Java"
    },
    {
          "Id":5,
          "Authors":"Shyama",
          "tags":"C#,C++"
    }
    ]
```

//Controller that i have created

$scope.request = response.data;//request contain all json data

//---------- logic to create new json------------
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var json = [
    {
          "Id":1,
          "Authors":[
             {
                "Id":10,
                "Name":"Arun"
             },
             {
                "Id":14,
                "Name":"Arjun"
             }
          ],
          "tags":[
             {
                "Name":"Java"
             }
          ]
    },
    {
          "Id":5,
          "Authors":[
             {
                "Id":7,
                "Name":"Shyama"
             }
          ],
          "tags":[
             {
                "Name":"C#"
             },
             {
                "Name":"C++"
             }
          ]
       }
    ];
for (var i=0, j=json.length; i<j; i++) {
    json[i].Authors = json[i].Authors.map(function(item) {return item.Name;}).join(',');
    json[i].tags = json[i].tags.map(function(item) {return item.Name;}).join(',');
}
console.log(json);
```